# why do i have to change the environment path every time when i open a new terminal? I am a beginner and now is learning tutorials, Thank you

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

minphie@Lenovo:~$ rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_sever
[rospack] Error: package 'beginner_tutorials' not found

As above, I know enter the catkin space and
$ source ./devel/setup.bash
can resolve the problem. But every time when I open a new terminal I have to do this step. Is there another way to solve the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223890/why-do-i-have-to-change-the-environment-path-every-time-when-i-open-a-new-terminal?-i-am-a-beginner-and-now-is-learning-tutorials,-thank-you./) by [Minphie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25528/minphie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit the file `~/.bashrc`  and at the end, add the line:

```
source PATH_TO_YOUR_CATKIN_WS/devel/setup.bash
```

This way every time you open a new terminal your catkin work space will be properly setup.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2016-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Minphie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25528/minphie/) on 2016-01-12**:
Thank you very much, that works for me.